# Find list with entries which have max version of this entries

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have some entities which uses a slowly changing versioning by version-number without a current-version-flag. My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private long functionalKey;
  private String name;
  private int version;
}
```

There are entries like:

- { id = 1, functionalKey = 1, name = "Test1", version = 1 }
- { id = 2, **functionalKey = 18**, name = "Test2", version = 1 }
- { id = 32, **functionalKey = 18**, name = "New Test 2", version = 2 }

How can I use Spring data to find all entries (by functionalKey) with the highest version number?

To find a single entry I can use something like `MyEntity findFirstByFunctionalKeyOrderByVersionDesc(long functionalKey)` or write a suitable expression statement. But I want all entities not only one! I search for something like `List<MyEntity> findAllWithHighestVersionGroupedByFunctionalKey`.

How is this possible?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Here is the list of things you can achieve with query methods https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation . You should use JPQL.